# How to define if there's an error in object with multiple array

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const data = {
      test1: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
      ],
      test2: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: 'theres an error in this field'},
        {error: 'theres an error here'},
      ],
      test3: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: 'theres an error'},
        {error: 'theres an error here'},
      ]
    };
```

how to check if the array has an error. which it should display an error message.

for example I have a `<div>` with condition and the `data` return `true` once there's only one true it will display the error message.

here's my code

```
 const test1 = data.test1.some(x => x.error !== ''); 
    const test2 = data.test2.some(x => x.error !== ''); 
    const test3 = data.test3.some(x => x.error !== ''); 
    
        <div *ngIf="test1 || test2 || test3">
            DISPLAY ERROR
        </div>
```

I'm not sure it this is the correct way.

Comment: Are you trying to display the specific errors if there are any?

Comment: Please __add context__ to your question. What do you need that for and why typescript ? Together with this `if` attribute in HTML it looks like [tag:Angular] .. correct ? Then there is a little trick you oversaw ️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get an array of the values of the properties of the object and use `some`, and within the `some` callback you can return the result of your `some` calls on the value if it's an array:

```
const hasError = Object.values(data).some(value => Array.isArray(value) && value.some(x => x.error));
```

If you know all the properties are these `testX` properties, you can drop the `Array.isArray` part.

Live Example:

```js
const dataWithError = {
    test1: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
      ],
    test2: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: 'theres an error in this field'},
        {error: 'theres an error here'},
    ],
    test3: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: 'theres an error'},
        {error: 'theres an error here'},
    ]
};
const dataWithoutError = {
    test1: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
      ],
    test2: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
    ],
    test3: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
    ]
};

const dataWithErrorHasError = Object.values(dataWithError).some(
    value => Array.isArray(value) && value.some(x => x.error)
);
console.log(`dataWithError:`, dataWithErrorHasError);

const dataWithoutErrorHasError = Object.values(dataWithoutError).some(
    value => Array.isArray(value) && value.some(x => x.error)
);
console.log(`dataWithoutError:`, dataWithoutErrorHasError);
```

Or for just specific properties from `data`, build the array directly:

```
const hasError = [data.test1, data.test2, data.test3].some(test => test.some(x => x.error));
```

Live Example:

```js
const dataWithError = {
    test1: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
      ],
    test2: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: 'theres an error in this field'},
        {error: 'theres an error here'},
    ],
    test3: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: 'theres an error'},
        {error: 'theres an error here'},
    ]
};
const dataWithoutError = {
    test1: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
      ],
    test2: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
    ],
    test3: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
    ]
};

const dataWithErrorHasError = [dataWithError.test1, dataWithError.test2, dataWithError.test3].some(test => test.some(x => x.error));
console.log(`dataWithError:`, dataWithErrorHasError);

const dataWithoutErrorHasError = [dataWithoutError.test1, dataWithoutError.test2, dataWithoutError.test3].some(test => test.some(x => x.error));
console.log(`dataWithoutError:`, dataWithoutErrorHasError);
```

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR:**  Can use `['test1', 'test3'].some(field => nonEmptyErrors(data[field]))`. See how functional JS-patterns work in different solutions.

#### Chaining conditions

In `test1 || test2 || test3` your are chaining tests with boolean OR `||`. The boolean OR is [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), means the first `true` in evaluation of this chain wins.

The same can be done more flexible using the functional [`some(predicate)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) test in JavaScript.

I want to explain some functional ingredients before showing you the solving recipe.

### Functional Basics

#### Arrays in pipelines: Filter, Map, Reduce

JavaScript uses [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find any objects that satisfy the *predicate*.

Can combine it with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as [*chained methods*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) to build a [*data-pipeline*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(computing)). This approach is often called ["streaming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computer_science)).

#### `Objects` to arrays

First you have to get a stream from your object `data`.
This can be done using factory methods:

- [`Objects.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [`Objects.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`Objects.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

### Functionals applied

Let's use the functional-basics explained above and build a chained pipeline to test, if your `data` object *has errors*.

Finally, we combine following *functional* ingredients

1. `nonEmptyErrors`: use a lambda *predicate* to filter elements
2. `map`, `reduce` and `some` as shortcuts (syntactic sugar)

to:

3. `hasErrors(data)`: a convenient function which returns a boolean
4. test selected properties `['test1', 'test3']` only

```js
const data = {
  test1: [
    {error: ''},
    {error: ''},
  ],
  test2: [
    {error: ''},
    {error: 'theres an error in this field'},
    {error: 'theres an error here'},
  ],
  test3: [
    {error: ''},
    {error: 'theres an error'},
    {error: 'theres an error here'},
  ]
};

// (0) data: tests with array of errors as string, some empty

// (1) define a filter lambda (can be used as function)
let nonEmptyErrors = arr => arr.filter(el => el.error !== '');

// (2) count specific elements with map-reduce
let countNonEmptyErrors = Object.entries(data)
  .map(([key, value]) => {
      let errors = nonEmptyErrors(value);
      console.log(key, errors.length);
      return errors;
    })
  // sum/count elements
  .reduce((acc, elem)=>{acc += elem.length; return acc;}, 0);
  // .flat().length;
console.log("countNonEmptyErrors", countNonEmptyErrors);


// (3) reuse the filter as predicate in a convenient function
function hasErrors(data) {
  return Object.values(data).some(nonEmptyErrors);
}
console.log("data has errors?", hasErrors(data));

// (4) filter selected properties of an object
console.log("test1, test3 | any errors: ", 
  ['test1', 'test3'].some(field => nonEmptyErrors(data[field]))
);
```